# Doing HTTP POST to dictionary object as form data

Tags: vbscript, http-post

I have a code in vbscript that works with Dictionary object. I would like to POST this object as his to the server, instead of writing: key1=value1&key2=value2&...&keyN=valueN.
 Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP forms send text and multi-part data, but not script objects.

It means you will need to send your Dictionary object either as a (converted) string of text or as binary data attached to your form.  Then you will need to convert that data back to a Dictionary object on your server.

For example you can write a sub to convert your Dictionary to an XML string, send it as a hidden field value, then on your server read in that XML string and convert it to a Dictionary.  Finally, if you are not happy with HTTP you can consider a client-server app instead of a web page.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. I have converted the Dictionary object to the string.